# How to correctly use the DateTime feature below

Tags: php

I have a timepicker where the textbox (durationChosen) formats the time like this '00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs'.. Now the problem is that I want this time to be inserted into the database but obviously the format is incorrect. I want the textbox format to remain the same but how can I insert the time correctly in the database with the correct format?

At the moment the code below is causing the page not to load and because of this it is not inserting anything in the database. Have I coded the DateTime feature below incorrectly:

Below is the code for the INSERT VALUES:

```
    $time = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'h * i * s *', $_POST['durationChosen'] );
    $sql="
      INSERT INTO Session (SessionDuration)
      VALUES ('" . $time->format( 'H:i:s' ) . "')";

 mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use this:
`$time = date("H:i:s", strtotime($_POST["durationChosen"]));`

Comment: I tried this but no matter what the duration is, it will display in the database '01:00:00'.

Comment: What is $_POST["duration"] for example?

Answer (score 1):

Lets the datepicker return a valid ISO duration string like

```
$duration = "PT3H12M36S";
```

Now you can use `DateInteval`

```
$time = new DateTime;
$time->add(new DateInterval($duration);
```

As a side note: MySQL accepts an ISO formatted string for every of its DATE*-typed columns

```
VALUES (' . $time->format('c')  . ')
```

http://php.net/datetime

Comment: Does same thing, page doesn't load. I did this  VALUES (' . $time->format($_POST['durationChosen'])  . '). Is this incorrect?

Comment: I assume you didn't see my first sentence. Also read this: http://php.net/dateinterval.construct